# symfony2 webprofiler show prod environment

Tags: symfony

The system in the dev environment going very slow with jquery but in prod me very well, could put the webprofiler in the prod environment? greetings and thanks

Answer (score 16):

Add this to `routing.yml`:

```
_wdt:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml"
    prefix:   /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
    prefix:   /_profiler
```

Add this to `config_prod.yml`:

```
web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
```

Change this in `AppKernel.php`:

Remove `$bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle()` from this statement:

```php
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
    // ...
}
```

and add this to the bundles array outside of the if statement:

```
new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle()
```

In `app.php` set debug=true

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

In `config_prod.yml` add:

```
framework:
    profiler:
        only_exceptions: false
```

That should do the trick.

Don't forgot to execute this after making the code changes:

```
$ php ./app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

Comment: then ? how do you invoke the profiler ? does it show up like that ? because that didn't work for me

Comment: 2 years later you may have found the answer, but for the records: go to your url/_profiler

Comment: Dont forget to

- set debug on true in app.php : 
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);

- in config_prod.yml add : 
framework:
    profiler:
        only_exceptions: false