# Web profiler toolbar in prod environment, best practice?

Tags: symfony

What would be the best practice for debugging on Symfony2 production website using profiler toolbar?
Log files are good but what if I need more info, eg. doctrine queries, routing, etc.

Comment: Use the dev environment.

Comment: Solution in post below (please see my comment in bottom) http://stackoverflow.com/a/13101667/564015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prod environments is not intended to debug application. You should never enable debug mode on production server (`prod` env). You can see what was wrong (errors ect.) in log files `app/logs/prod.log`.

You should debug doctrine, routing etc. on `dev`, `staging`, `preProd` etc. servers - places where you run application in `dev` env.

Comment: In addition, in accordance with good practice SensioLabs the app_dev.php file should never be accesible in a production environment (in any way, the file must not exist on the server).

Comment: I disagree: for testing on production is good idea, for example in performance in app_dev you build routing from scratch and times are mess up! - if You rely want to find what slows You'rs app down you need to check on cached data so on prod.